# toBase64 encoding in Qt does not result in a printable QString

Tags: c++, qt

I've replicated this in two places in my code, one written by me and the one I'm posting an image of, that was written by someone else. I can't get the base64 to output to qDebug at all. I thought base64 was supposed to be readable. It has a size. But it won't print the entire qDebug line.

Thanks in advance for any help.

[image]

Here's the code. I'm on Qt Kit 5.12.1 64 bit mingw in release.

```
    QFile* file = new QFile("C:\\Qr-Pic\\Poll_Directory\\IMG_00000001 - Copy (53).jpg");
    file->open(QIODevice::ReadOnly);
    QByteArray image = file->readAll();
    int originalSize = image.length();

    QString encoded = QString(image.toBase64());
    int encodedSize = encoded.size();

    qDebug() << "encodedSize=" << encodedSize;
    qDebug() << "encode=" << encoded;
```

Output:

```
encodedSize= 34036
```

Comment: Please post the code instead of image of the code. Same goes for the output of the program.

Comment: By the way, although it's irrelevant to your question, your file is leaked.

Comment: @RSahu Just added the code and output

Comment: @replete I tried running it in a console window, I put it in a folder where I have all of Qt's dependencies, and I get no output from that.

Comment: Instead of running from a console, you could of course also print a slice of the output with `QString::left` etc., or dump it to a text file. If the result looks correct it's more evidence that the total output is too large for the tab.

Comment: Ah I think you solved it, it looks like using left I was able to get printable characters.

Comment: @sand_storm_of_code.txt: Please post your `.pro` file with your question.